# Easy example to put HTML with CSS into an NSTextView?

Tags: html, css, nstextview

Is there an easy way to put HTML with CSS into an NSText or NSTextView? Once I do that, I want to rotate it, put part of it in a view, generate the output, then repeat...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a WebView and embed the CSS into the HTML.

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:<yourstring> baseURL:nil];
```